# Eclipse custom code style profile parameters

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to add a custom format setting to eclipse? I would like to have my closing parentheses followed by spaces, unless they're followed by either another parenthesis, a period, or a semicolon, and none of the current options in the Formatter seem to allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom formatter profiles in the Preferences for each language that is supported by your Eclipse installation. 
`Window -> Preferences -> Java (or other desired language) -> Code Style -> Formatter` 
Here you can add, edit, export and import multiple profiles for the formatter. 
Using Ctrl+Shift+F will apply the currently chosen format to the opened source file. Right click on any package or project -> Source -> Format does the same to all selected / contained files.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it very clear in my question at first, but the question IS about adding custom options to the formatter. For example, under Expressions->Parenthesized expressions, there are three options: before opening parens, after opening parens, before closing parens. What if I want a space after closing parens? What if I want a space after closing parens, unless there's another parenthesis there?

Comment: I am not quite sure whether it is possible to easily add these customised formatting options to the built-in formatter. There are plugins that might be able to do this though. Maybe give Jalopy (http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/jalopy/index.html) a try.