# Notify Coding standards violation on Eclipse Editor while developers are writing code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin on eclipse which helps to check the code written in Eclipse Editor against some coding best practices  ?

The features which i am looking for exactly are :

1. ***The violations of coding standards should appear as warning on the Eclipse Editor itself against the line which violates it. (Same way warnings are shown using the yellow triangular symbol)***
2. ***The coding standard itself should be easily editable ( I may be able to include or exclude some rules ). I want it to be tailored according to my organization's coding standards.***
3. ***Should check against standards in `.java` , `.jsp` and `.js` files.***

There are tools which can help in achieving that but they need to be run explicitly and can be run only when code is written completely.

I want the developers to be notified the instant they are going against coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a plugin.  Eclipse can generate warnings based on style problems:-

`Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings`

You can even get it to auto-format when files are saved:-

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> Format Source Code`

**WARNING**: Enforcing this will annoy developers.

Also see [Eclipse custom code style parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950762/eclipse-custom-code-style-profile-parameters)

Comment: But can the rules against which code is checked be modified easily ? I want to customize it according to my organizations standards.

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950762/eclipse-custom-code-style-profile-parameters

Comment: Seems like they will only work for java files. What about other files ?

Comment: Never tried with others but I assume it's the same procedure, just looking at other sub menus than `Java`